# while executing jar getting error javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, maven

I have built a jar using maven. While running it I am getting exception. If I run it from eclipse main program, it works fine. But when I Build the jar and executes it, It throws Exception. How can I make it working with jar as well?

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.staples</groupId>
<artifactId>CouponAllocationConsumer</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>CouponAllocation</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
    <spring.version>3.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.batch.version>2.2.0.RELEASE</spring.batch.version>
    <mysql.driver.version>5.1.25</mysql.driver.version>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <maven.compiler.plugin>3.1</maven.compiler.plugin>
    <maven.eclipse.plugin>2.9</maven.eclipse.plugin>
</properties>
<build>
    <finalName>CouponAllocation</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.eclipse.plugin}</version>
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.compiler.plugin}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- exclude junit, we need runtime dependency only -->
                        <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependency-jars/</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/log4j.properties</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>com.staples.couponallocation.kafkastorm.SpoutMainTopology</mainClass>
                        <classpathPrefix>./dependency-jars/</classpathPrefix>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2-beta-4</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- Json and GSon jar -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20140107</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>




    <!-- Spring XML to/back object -->
    <!-- dependency> <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId> 
        <version>${spring.version}</version> </dependency -->

    <!-- MySQL database driver -->
    <!-- dependency> <groupId>mysql</groupId> <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId> 
        <version>${mysql.driver.version}</version> </dependency -->

    <!-- Spring Batch dependencies -->

    <!-- Spring Batch unit test -->

    <!-- Storm kafka jar -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-kafka</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.3</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.9.1</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.2.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>

            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
                <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
            </exclusion>

        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.3</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
                <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>provided</scope>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- LOG4J -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
        <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.6</version>

        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Please add exception log too if you can.

Comment: I am getting this Exception.java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named RewardsRealTime at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:128) at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchWhenAvailable(DisruptorQueue.java:99) at backtype.storm.disruptor$consume_batch_when_available.invoke(disruptor.clj:80) at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__3441$fn__3453$fn__3500.invoke(executor.clj:748) at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__464.invoke(util.clj:463) at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24